# WearOS + iPhone messaging

Tags: android, wear-os

WearOS is marketed by Google as being compatible with both Android and iPhones, however I can find no way to have the iPhone programatically send data to (and from) a WearOS application (like is possible on Android)

For example, in my WearOS standalone app I can use Wearable.MessageApi to send data messages to the corresponding Android application (receiving with a MessageApi.MessageListener)

On iOS, how can I achieve the same messaging as with the Android? I have searched around everywhere and cannot find anything (apart from Google's implication in their marketing) that this is even possible at all

Edit: I should specify that when I say messaging, this has nothing to do with text messaging or cloud messages or notifications meant for users, I am talking about an API that lets me pass specific data packets to-and-from the WearOS app and a linked companion app on the phone (e.g. When selecting a button in my WearOS app, a message is delivered to the iOS app, letting it know that the button has been clicked)

Comment: Maybe not what you want, but there is an iOS folder in here https://github.com/bevkoski/react-native-android-wear-demo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Android wear 2.0 has its own GCM/FCM Registration ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185400/does-android-wear-2-0-has-its-own-gcm-fcm-registration-id)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately it is not quite what i'm after. I suppose using FCM could work, but the messaging should be able to function even while offline (like it does with an Android device)

Answer (score 0):

There was already similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727896/direct-communication-between-wear-os-and-ios-companion-app/56076650#56076650).
So shorlty, as I wrote in response to popsted issue.
As far as I know there is no such a thing as WearOS<->iOS messaging API.
You need to create your own comminication via internet or bluetooth (not sure how it will work). As far as I know, Google suggestion is to use Firebase messaging.