# Direct communication between Wear OS and iOS companion app

Tags: ios, wear-os

I currently have an app for Android & iOS smartphones which I want to bring to Wear OS & Watch OS.

As Wear OS smartwatches are also compatible with iOS devices, I'm looking for a way to communicate between the Watch OS app and the iOS app.

I wasn't able to find anything about this yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no simple way to communicate between WearOS device and Iphones.
On one hand you can try to use regular bluetooth or BLE, on the other hand
the android smartwatch apps might be now standalone with direct Internet access.
You might want to create the standaolne app and synchronize via Internet, eg. Firebase Cloud Messaging.